# sodium chloride and amylase activity

Tags: enzymes

So, I did an experiment on the effect of sodium chloride on amylase. and I found out the higher the concentration, the slower the activity.

Therefore, is it valid to make the assumption that when we consume food with starch and high salt concentration, it can affect our digestion of starch? like slower break down of starch?

Answer (score 2):

I highly suggest you actually look at studies that analyze this and there should be a good number since amylase is [a well defined enzyme](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1266978/). (Bailey K, Hopkins RH, Dolby DE)

Not only that but applying this type of logic to any problem results in bad conclusions and therefore is [bad science](http://www.ucmp.berkeley.edu/diapsids/buzz/dinoscience.html). (Berkeley)

The process of proving something scientifically is something that follows a somewhat predictable route. I only say that because not everything follows this exact path.

There is usually a nicer looking picture though I cannot seem to find it.

[image]([Source](http://www.hydroassoc.org/research-101-levels-of-evidence-in-hydrocephalus-clinical-research-studies/))

So to answer bluntly, no. You cannot make that conclusion with any stretch of the imagination.

Being that amylases are so well studied you may have your answer after a few google searches, but the case remains that it took many years of research to reliably say so.

Answer (score -1):

I found that the higher the concentration of NaCl, the higher the rate of reaction
Why is this different to yours?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site and then delete or [edit] your answer accordingly. In particular what you have posted is a comment, but you posted it as an answer. Answer are much more likely to receive a favorable response if they are actually answers and include supporting references (primary literature is best). Without that support, an answer is indistinguishable from opinion. Thanks! 